In KNative can I control the scale up decision frequency
In KNative I can configure the window used for autoscaling decisions using
autoscaling.knative.dev/window: "5m"
Is there a parameter that controls how often the scaleup decision can happen (e.g. every minute vs every 2 minutes)?

I believe the scale-up timing is based on the autoscaler computation interval, which is hard-coded to 2 seconds:
https://github.com/knative/serving/blob/main/pkg/autoscaler/scaling/multiscaler.go#L36
Given that the autoscaler is involved in scaling from zero to one instance, a 1 minute interval would mean an average cold-start time of more than 30s.
If you're looking for an autoscaler with this kind of slow movement, you can use Knative with the standard Kubernetes Horizontal Pod Autoscaler: https://knative.dev/docs/serving/autoscaling/autoscaler-types/
